# Why does core create RSS feeds for taxonomy terms?

Tags: 9, feeds

Drupal 9.5.8 standard installation; I never did anything about RSS feeds in that website.

In Google Search Console, under ***Crawled - currently not indexed*** section, I was surprised to come across this webpage:

```
example.com/taxonomy/term/NUMBER/feed
```

In `/admin/modules` I read that the (deprecated) module **Aggregator** isn't on, and I don't recall ever turning it on.

What may cause the RSS feed webpage to be created and how to prevent the creation of such webpages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drupal 9 standard profile creates RSS feeds for taxonomy terms by default.

If you don't want the feeds, you can remove (delete or disable) them from the taxonomy term view in Admin -> Structure -> Views.

Comment: In the Views list I have also found **Frontpage** view with `Feed (/rss.xml)
Page (/node)`. I don't use it and never has been. Would it be plausible to disable it as well?

Comment: @haidar Yes, you can disable them.  I am not sure whether the feeds provide any SEO benefit, but unless your site is updated quite frequently, any such benefit is probably negligible.